# GAS - Save files on trigger

Tags: google-apps-script

Is there a way to use apps script to save/backup files? So that I may set it on weekly trigger or something.

I looked up and found that it's possible to create files and place in folders,
 but even then, the File service is deprecated.
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/docs-list/file

Answer (score 0):

[Drive Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/) is what has replaced the docs service.